# How do I select every value that corresponds to another value in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, partitioning

The title may sound a little confusing but essentially what I am trying to do is I'm trying to pull from the table below. The query I used to create the table below was

```
    select d.FOLDER_ID, d.PKG_ID, p.file_id, d.PKG_START_TIME, d.PKG_END_TIME, d.ISVALID, d.VALIDFILE_COUNT, d.INVALIDFILE_COUNT, d.ISLOADED, d.LOADEDFILE_COUNT, d.REJECTEDFILE_COUNT 

from DATA_EXCHANGE_PACKAGE d  full outer join PACKAGE_FILE p on d.PKG_ID = p.PKG_ID

where d.pkg_id = p.pkg_id

order by PKG_START_TIME asc
```

This table contains data from two different tables as you can see in the query and it selects the first records based on package start time.

What I am trying to achieve is I want a query which can choose the amount of pkg_id's to return but I want every file_Id chosen for the amount of pkg_id chosen. For example, in my database I may have 100 packages but I only want to choose every file_Id  for the first 10 packages. How do I do this. I've only been able to choose the first 5 records using top and choose just 5 distinct pkg_id rows but not every file_id for those distinct 5 pkg_ID's. Any help would be appreciated. I understand group by and partition may work to achieve what I want but I haven't been successful. I'm not the greatest at SQL so this is why i'm struggling, I thought this query was going to be easier to create. I'm also  certain the where statement is pointless but I kept it regardless.

Also let's assume the folder_Id is always 1.

```
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+
| FOLDER_ID | PKG_ID | file_id |     PKG_START_TIME      |      PKG_END_TIME       | ISVALID | VALIDFILE_COUNT | INVALIDFILE_COUNT | ISLOADED | LOADEDFILE_COUNT | REJECTEDFILE_COUNT |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+
|         1 |      1 |       1 | 2019-11-19 14:59:24.343 | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL            | NULL              | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       2 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       3 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       4 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       5 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       6 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       7 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       8 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |       9 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |      10 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      2 |      11 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      12 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      13 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      14 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      15 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      16 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      17 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      18 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      19 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      20 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
|         1 |      3 |      21 | 2019-11-19 15:58:26.733 | NULL                    | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |
```

An example of what I want to achieve with the above data is only want to choose the first two distinct pkg_id's based on the pkg_start_time in ascending order. However when only choosing those two distinct pkg_id's I want every file_id for those pkg_id's outputted. The below table is what I want my query to select from the above table.

```
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| FOLDER_ID | PKG_ID | file_id |     PKG_START_TIME      | PKG_END_TIME | ISVALID | VALIDFILE_COUNT | INVALIDFILE_COUNT | ISLOADED | LOADEDFILE_COUNT | REJECTEDFILE_COUNT | seqnum |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
|         1 |      1 |       1 | 2019-11-19 14:59:24.343 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL            | NULL              | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      1 |
|         1 |      2 |       2 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      1 |
|         1 |      2 |       3 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      2 |
|         1 |      2 |       4 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      3 |
|         1 |      2 |       5 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      4 |
|         1 |      2 |       6 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      5 |
|         1 |      2 |       7 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      6 |
|         1 |      2 |       8 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      7 |
|         1 |      2 |       9 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      8 |
|         1 |      2 |      10 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |      9 |
|         1 |      2 |      11 | 2019-11-19 15:10:20.157 | NULL         | 1       | 10              | 0                 | NULL     | NULL             | NULL               |     10 |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

**Edit: I have solved my question**

Comment: What do you mean by `choose the amount of pkg_id records` in what order? Random?

Comment: I'd prefer for the order to be descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question I was asking. The query i have made which has solved my question is below.

```
select d.FOLDER_ID, d.PKG_ID, p.file_id, d.PKG_START_TIME, d.PKG_END_TIME, d.ISVALID, d.VALIDFILE_COUNT, d.INVALIDFILE_COUNT, d.ISLOADED, d.LOADEDFILE_COUNT, d.REJECTEDFILE_COUNT 

from DATA_EXCHANGE_PACKAGE d  full outer join PACKAGE_FILE p on d.PKG_ID = p.PKG_ID

where d.PKG_ID = p.PKG_ID and d.PKG_ID > (select max(d.PKG_ID) - 5 from DATA_EXCHANGE_PACKAGE d ) and d.FOLDER_ID = 1

order by PKG_START_TIME desc
```

This query will basically iterate through the table and select every record until 5 distinct pkg_id's have been chosen. I'm going to use this query in Python and set where that 5 value is as a parameter so users can choose the amount of packages they want to return. I could also instead of using max(d.PKG_Id). In this table every new package ID will be a value higher than the previous package ID so I could probably also use datetime and max but this query is good enough for now. Also the folder_ID value will be a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are using a `full join`, so I'm replacing it with an `inner join`.  You want `row_number()`:

```
select dp.*
from (select d.FOLDER_ID, d.PKG_ID, p.file_id, d.PKG_START_TIME, 
             d.PKG_END_TIME, d.ISVALID, d.VALIDFILE_COUNT, 
             d.INVALIDFILE_COUNT, d.ISLOADED, d.LOADEDFILE_COUNT, 
             d.REJECTEDFILE_COUNT,
             row_number() over (partition by d.pkg_id order by p.file_id) as seqnum
      from DATA_EXCHANGE_PACKAGE d inner join
           PACKAGE_FILE p
           on d.PKG_ID = p.PKG_ID
      where d.pkg_id = p.pkg_id
     ) dp
where seqnum <= 10
order by PKG_START_TIME asc
```

Comment: I just realized I poorly worded my question, i'm sorry for my poor wording, i'll edit my original question to fix fix the confusion. What I meant to write  is I want to only choose distinct pkg_id's but I want every file_id chosen for those distinct pkg_id's. So if I want to only choose the first two pkg_id's here. Then every file_id for those two pkg_id's should be chosen. I've still up voted your answer though because it's my fault for the confusion, sorry.

Comment: @CanadianBeaver That's not how 1 to many relational query works, If you want every file id for each package then there will be repeated pkg id. Your question is still not clear.

Comment: I'm okay with the pkg_id being repeated. For example in the following chart above If I wanted to only choose every file_id for the first two distinct pkg_id's then I'd like my query to be able to do that. or If I wanted to instead choose every file_id for the first 5 distinct packages then i'd like to do that as well. I'll make another chart below the original chart which shows what I want the query to do.